# Convert integers to time and add

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have requirement to converting integer value to time format using javascript.

My requirement is that the result should be in time format.

Example `08:55` and `09:55`

If I add these two as numbers then I will get `18.10` but I need `18:50`

Comment: Example is not clear enough

Comment: for example i have integer value like 08:50 then it should be 18:50 in hh:mm format.@Satpal

Comment: Why would `08:55` become `18:50`?

Comment: @DavidThomas OP means if we sum both `08:55` and `09:55`.

Comment: Calculating the sum of two times is nonsense. It is an impossible operation. What would "8 o'clock + 12 o'clock" give you? Or do you mean e.g. "8 o'clock + 12 hours"?

Comment: i edited my question.please see that again.@ThiefMaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (***My solution assumes the sum of times is not more than 24 hours***)

```
function pad(str) { 
    return ("00"+str).slice(-2);
} 
var str1 = "08:55";
var str2 = "09:55";
var token1 = str1.split(":");
var token2 = str2.split(":");
var result = token1[0] * 60 + + token1[1] + + token2[0] * 60 + + token2[1];
var newTime = pad(Math.floor(result/60)) + ":" + pad(result % 60);
console.log(newTime);
```

Comment: thanks Mr_green,i got my perfect answer,but i want to know how you do this and whats the logic behind this.@Mr_green

Comment: @SumitPathak the end for normal numbers is `100`.. whereas for time is `60`. So, I just multiplied the hundreds digit of number with `60` instead of `100`. and also you might have observed that I used `+ +` instead of just `+`. this technique is for converting strings to numbers. I don't know whether they are compatible with all browsers. if you are in doubt then use `parseInt("stringNumber", 10)` . refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: `function pad(str) { return ("00"+str).slice(-2)}` and `var newTime = pad(Math.floor(result/60)) + ":" + pad(result % 60);` unless you want `17:4` when adding `08:02+09:02`. Also "10:02"+"15:05" will give 25:07 instead of 01:07 next day - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/umkj5/

Comment: @mplungjan true.. while coding I assumed that the sum of times is less than 24. I think it will be better if I mention this in my post. will do it now.

Comment: and pad or you will get 8:2